# Cannot save GuiXT script from SAP

Tags: file, vbscript, record, sap-gui

I cannot save GUIscript from recorder. I am using two systems F6P and Q06, and in F6P I can record a script and save the file, but in Q06 I cannot save a vbs file.
I press record and then stop and a file should be created in the destination path, but no file is created. The destination path is valid.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First change the path to desktop or other destination where you have have access to , then record the script after you stop it, It will be saved.